# dynamic pivot table with duplicate column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have the following table:

```
Name       |       Value
---------------------------
key1       |       val1
key2       |       val2
key1       |       val3
key4       |       val4
.          |       .
.          |       .
.          |       .
.          |       .
```

I need the output to be as follows:

```
key1       |    key2       |    key1       |    key4      |    ......
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
val1       |    val2       |    val3       |    val4      |    ......
```

I have tried achieving this using dynamic pivot, but it fails because the key1 is a duplicate column.

SQLError:
The column 'key1' was specified multiple times for 'p'.

Pivot Query that I used:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33f66/4

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved by pivot, but depending on the output requirements there might be other solutions. Do you need to create a new table with the results or just display/print/export it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not possible using a pivot as the column names are identical. Here is another solution:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = STUFF((SELECT ',''' + value + ''' as ' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                    from mytable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

EXEC ('select '+ @sql)
```

Result:

```
key1    key2    key1    key4
val1    val2    val3    val4
```

Comment: the requirement is to select all the columns in the result table. I understand the columns need to be unique in the pivot. Do you see an approach (other than pivoting, maybe) to get the results that i require.

Comment: @user3796907 it is a really good idea to post the actual code with the question

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear enough. But i have mentioned in the question itself the output that i am expecting. The only code that i have at this moment is in the sqlfiddle that i have posted. Maybe i am not understanding your question properly. Can you elaboarte more please?

Comment: clausen, i ran the query you gave but i am not seeing the same results. here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad490/1

Comment: It shows the correct result when I try it on my own server, but SQL Fiddle is omitting key3 for some reason.

Comment: Jerrad, indeed. Thanks.
Can you guys explain this query to me. I have never used stuff XML Path before.

Comment: @Jerrad key3 is not part of the data. So what exactly do you mean ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, sorry, I meant val3.  When I run the Fiddle, it only returns 3 columns.

Comment: @Jerrad you can't trust fiddle. I have seen it give wrong results in other cases.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, like I said, it was correct when I tried it on my server.  This is the first time I've seen SQL Fiddle just completely skip a column like that.